# How to catch errors on Winston Http Transport

Tags: node.js, logging, https, winston

I'm creating a logging framework using winston. Basically using built in winston http transport. My question is, how should I catch any http exceptions that might have occurred while making http post request due to invalid host/path/auth. Below is my code structure-

```
    const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = format;

const transportOptions = {
  host: 'host',
  port: 'port',
  path: '/',
  auth: '',
};

const myFormat = printf(debug => {
    var msg = {
      timestamp: debug.timestamp,
      label: debug.label,
      level: debug.level,
      message: debug.message,
    };
    return JSON.stringify(msg);
  });

  const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: combine(label({ label: 'label' }), timestamp(), myFormat),
    transports: [
      new transports.Console(),
      new transports.Http(transportOptions),
    ],
    json: false,
  });

logger.info('Test');
```

If I provide wrong value in `transportOptions` it just does nothing. I want my framework through some sort of exception so that I would know when any error/exception occurs. Can anyone please give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/http.js#L57 , it looks like the HTTP transport emits a `'warn'` event if the HTTP response code isn't 200.  So as long as your server returns non-200 when there's an error, then you could listen to the `'warn'` event from your transport and process the error accordingly (throw an exception or whatever you want).  Here is example code (I tested and it works):

```
// Declare your transport outside the logger definition
const t = new transports.Http(transportOptions);
...
t.on('warn', (e) => console.log('warning! ' + e));
logger.info('Test'); // 'warning! ...'
```

Note that if the server gives no response, then the transport doesn't report a warning; whether that is a bug or feature I'm not sure... :)